# Understanding the differences in different usages of 'system'

Tags: perl

What is the difference between these two usages of `system`?

```
$cmd = "/my/code.pl";
$status = system("$cmd $var1");
```

vs

```
$cmd = "/my/code.pl";
$status = system("$cmd", "$var1");
```

Comment: What is `$var1`?  Make sure to `use strict` and `use warnings`.

Comment: By the way, all those quotes in `system("$cmd", "$var1")` are useless.

Comment: Another difference is that the second one has Useless Quotes, it should be $status = system($cmd, $var1)    :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first (one string) invocation of [`system`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system.html) runs the system shell to run the command, and (amongst other things) means that the arguments to the command (from `$var1`) will undergo shell expansion.

The second version with plural arguments bypasses the system shell and the arguments undergo no further shell processing.  It is generally the recommended way of doing things.  Note, however, that it means you have to worry about I/O redirection.  If that's an issue, then the first form (used carefully) is simpler.  Alternatively, explore CPAN to find modules to assist - there are bound to be some.

Answer (score 4):

The latter is better (in most circumstances) because it explicitly passes each individual parameter to the specified command as a single command line argument.

In the former version, any spaces present in `$cmd` or `$var1` would result in additional (and likely unwanted) command line arguments being sent.

To give an example, given `$cmd = "cat"` and  `$var1 = "/tmp/my test file"` the first line will result in:

```
cat /tmp/my test file  # three parameters
```

and the second would give:

```
cat "/tmp/my test file"  # one parameter
```

So the first version would break the filename in two (and probably produce "file not found" errors), but the second version would keep `$var1` intact as a single parameter.

However if you need to redirect the output of the command ( e.g. `1> logfile 2>&1` ), or other features of the shell (globbing, pipes, etc), then you need to use the first version.

Comment: What you say is correct, but the `echo` example is a bad one ... works either way.

Comment: If I have $status = system("$cmd $var1 $var2");  How would the 2nd option look like?

Comment: @BrianRoach yeah, that's what I said!

Comment: @Alnitak - sorry, must have missed it.

Answer (score 2):

From: http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system.html

> Note that argument processing varies depending on the number of arguments. If there is more than one argument in LIST, or if LIST is an array with more than one value, starts the program given by the first element of the list with arguments given by the rest of the list. If there is only one scalar argument, the argument is checked for shell metacharacters, and if there are any, the entire argument is passed to the system's command shell for parsing (this is /bin/sh -c on Unix platforms, but varies on other platforms). If there are no shell metacharacters in the argument, it is split into words and passed directly to execvp , which is more efficient.

This means that if you need a shell (for example you're going to use a pipe `|`, e.g. `./someprog | wc` for example) you need to use the first method in your example.